# ls command that shows AM/PM

Tags: linux, centos7, ls

I'm using a CentOS 7 OS, configured based on AM/PM.
Is there a linux command line (like ls --full-time) that shows full time information including AM/PM?

Below example does not show AM/PM:

```
# ls --full-time
# -rw-------. 1 root root 125274133976 2021-06-10 05:43:58.348897593 -0700 file1.tar.gz
# -rw-------. 1 root root 187085036220 2021-06-10 08:28:56.257324419 -0700 file2.tar.gz
```

Comment: Have you tried using `--time-style` with a format string including `%p`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Doug Deden's hint, I was able to figure out the ls command line.
Below is the ls command that delivers exactly the results I needed:

```
# ls -h  -l --time-style="+%F %r"
# total 285G
# -rw-------. 1 root root 110G 2021-06-11 06:38:57 AM file1.tar.gz
# -rw-------. 1 root root 175G 2021-06-11 04:37:54 PM file2.tar.gz
```